# vs 2008 javascript intellisense in XML file problem

Tags: .net, javascript, xml, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I am trying to get javascript intellisense to work for jQuery in a .xml file. I've already used a custom XSD to provide intellisense for the XML. Under the  tag, I have a mixture of HTML and javascript which are enclosed by . And it is all greyed out so no intellisense there.

Adding a ///  does not help as well.

I would really like to be able to have intellisense when writing javascript in the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx

This is a hot fix for java script intellisense that may help.

Comment: I had tried that before. It doesn't work. The .xml file extension seems to be lefted out.

Answer (score 0):

I can either get javascript intellisense or xml intellisense working one at a time but not both together by adjusting Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension.

This makes me think that this should be tweakable more somewhere. The registry?